# Model selection, when candidates have been fit to two separate data sets independently...anything beyond multiplying likelihoods?

Tags: model-selection, aic, likelihood

I have a series of candidate spatial capture-recapture models--but 2 or 3 of these models end up generating data vectors that R can't allocate when considering the entire dataset.  I've split observations into two groups, and fit each candidate model twice, and have been able to piece together estimates and variance using the delta method...but I'm not sure how to go about model selection.  After multiplying each model's log-likelihoods, differences in candidate AIC values that were approximately 1-2 when considering the entire data set are >1,000.  Is it defensible to average each model's log-likelihoods or AIC weight for comparison?

Thanks!